# Rouge-N precision score for multiple reference summaries

Tags: nlp, summarization, machine-translation

I am writing the code for ROUGE-N score used in Machine Translation and Text Summarization domains.

The [original paper for ROUGE Score](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W04-1013) says that ROUGE-N is a recall score . The paper also mentions the formula for calculating the ROUGE-N score for a candidate summary when we have multiple reference summaries.

However after going through few blogs I found that , there is something called the ROUGE-N precision score which is equal to the fraction of n-grams present in the candidate summary that matches with reference summary.

However I have got no idea as to how to tweak this formula while we are having multiple reference summaries instead of one.

Comment: Follow that one paper and implement it as it is on that paper first. Ignore everything else, then be critical after you have successfully replicated the paper.